# Is torch obligatory to run transformers library?

Tags: python, keras, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use pretrained models from transformers library, but would prefer to use tensorflow backend. While running the code below I receive the error:

```
#import torch
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, TFDistilBertModel

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_tf_distilbert because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so: undefined symbol: cudaGraphInstantiateWithFlags, version libcudart.so.11.0
```

And the error disappears when importing torch. Does it mean that that torch module is strictly required for transformers and it is not possible to use tf as its replacement? If it is possible, how to do this correctly?

Comment: Most of `transformers` is PyTorch only.